# laravel cashier not working with jessengers mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I am trying to use laravel/cashier with jessengers MongoDB.
I am using Laravel 5.2 and Jessenger  MongoDb Extension

```
$user->newSubscription($plan_data['name'], $plan_data['id'])->create($stripeToken);
```

Getting this **error:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getDateFormat() on null in
>   /location/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 2990
>       Call to a member function getDateFormat() on null

I already Tried:

[Github Issue #222](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/222)

[Github Issue #904](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/904)

[Github Issue #618](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/618)

Comment: Get any joy with this?

Comment: hey, Matt, No I did not get any solution, I used another plugin which is not the cashier, If you need the name let me know. I just forget.
It was for the subscriptions with the stripe.

Comment: Yeh, i figured that mongo was probably going to give me more problems with integrations further down the road... I ended up going back to postgres with multiple databases and use mongo db/driver just for the tables that i need mongo for. Thanks though!

Comment: yeah, A lot, even php7 is still not properly supported by jessenger and I was ended up degrading to php5 for oauth2 server for MongoDB jessenger laravel.

Comment: Ah! So far no issues with php7 for myself, my requirements are pretty basic however!

Comment: cool :) thats good.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to use the AliasLoader and simply provide Subscription.class and SubscriptionItem.class with my own models.

Copy Subscription.class and SubscriptionItem.class from Cashier into your Models folder.

- Change namespace to your Models namespace
- Replace model class import to `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;`

In AppServiceProvider add

```
$loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();

$loader->alias(Subscription::class, \App\Models\Subscription::class);
$loader->alias(SubscriptionItem::class, \App\Models\SubscriptionItem::class);
```